# Is there an interface like ICollection<t>, but designed for sorted collections?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

...or can I use ICollection with no problem?

I mean, I don't think ICollection was designed for Sorted collections because that could break an application designed for sorted or unserted ICollection objects, but I don't know.

Comment: See the defintion of SortedDictionary: `public class SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable {}`

Comment: [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) and [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) both inherit from `ICollection`, as well as some other interfaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say the [ICollection<T> Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) is suitable for implementation by sorted collection types, because a sorted collection can be enumerated, added to, removed from, cleared and checked for its contents.

As a counter-example, the [IList<T> Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)  is probably not suitable, because unlike ICollection<T> it assumes that the collection is a list where the elements can be added at specific positions, which doesn't make sense if the collection itself determines the position of each element.

The sorted collection types in the .NET Framework (the [SortedList<TKey, TValue> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx), [SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx), and [SortedSet<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx)) all implement ICollection<T> but not IList<T>.

Answer (score 1):

This interface can be used to sorted enumerables:

`IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iorderedenumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1